# FLVPlayback Flash Skin not showing in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, flash, controls, skin, flvplayback

Im trying to insert a flash video with controls in my website. I can see the video but not the controls with FLVPlayback. I put all my files at the same level of my page, so i shouldnt have a path error...

Heres my files:

- Confr.flv
- Confr.swf
- MinimaFlatCustomColorPlayBackSeekCounterVolMute.swf (playerSkin)

My code:

```
<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" width="667" height="410" id="Confr" align="middle">
                <param name="movie" value="http://unikmedia.ca/ad/wp-content/themes/adapte/Confr.swf" />
                <param name="quality" value="best" />
                <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
                <param name="play" value="false" />
                <param name="loop" value="false" />
                <param name="wmode" value="window" />
                <param name="scale" value="showall" />
                <param name="menu" value="true" />
                <param name="devicefont" value="false" />
                <param name="salign" value="" />
                <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
                <!--[if !IE]>-->
                <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="http://unikmedia.ca/ad/wp-content/themes/adapte/Confr.swf" width="667" height="410">
                    <param name="movie" value="http://unikmedia.ca/ad/wp-content/themes/adapte/Confr.swf" />
                    <param name="quality" value="best" />
                    <param name="bgcolor" value="#ffffff" />
                    <param name="play" value="false" />
                    <param name="loop" value="false" />
                    <param name="wmode" value="window" />
                    <param name="scale" value="showall" />
                    <param name="menu" value="true" />
                    <param name="devicefont" value="false" />
                    <param name="salign" value="" />
                    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />
                <!--<![endif]-->
                    <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflash">
                        <img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" />
                    </a>
                <!--[if !IE]>-->
                </object>
                <!--<![endif]-->
            </object>
```

If you look at this link, you can see the player :http://unikmedia.ca/ad/wp-content/themes/adapte/Confr.swf

But in the wordpress, no controls at all... : http://unikmedia.ca/ad/a-propos/

Please I need help !!!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, and I found the solution... change the "swf BASE directory" in your embeded swf object. With this parameter pointing to your swf directory, the FLVPlayBack will be able to find the control skin swf.
Here's a sample:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    var flashvars = {};
    var params = {"base": "../project/subfolder/"};
    var attributes = {id: "Main", name: "Main"};
    swfobject.embedSWF("MainLoader.swf", "myAlternativeContent", "920", "550", "10.0.0", "expressInstall.swf", flashvars, params, attributes);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your file MinimaFlatCustomColorPlayBackSeekCounterVolMute.swf get an 404 error.

Try to find the script who call this file and change it.

But i suggest you to convert the .swf movie to an .mp4 and use jwplayer if its possible.

---

You can also try to create an 'a-propos' folder at the root of the site, like 'wp-content' folder, and put your 'MinimaFlatCustomColorPlayBackSeekCounterVolMute.swf' file in it

Comment: It will be supported on Apple devices and can play with html5

Comment: Unfortunalty, the format must be swf and nothing else. I've tried the folder at the root of my website, but it doesnt  work, the page is redirect to this folder... I really don't know how to link this file.

Answer (score -1):

I was having the same issue, in my local workspace I could see it, but on the WP live site I couldn't.  In my case I solved it by changing the permissions of the skin swf, try changing the chmod to 777 (of just skin swf file) to see if that's the issue.